# pthread same ID and output self_t

Tags: c, pthreads

i hope i will put my question very clear, i am programming pthread,Briefly i calculate the number of threads needed, and pass created threads to a function and back, the function does transpose on different blocks; so each thread has its own block.

To check that im sending different threads, i run pthread_t self_t, but face two problems:
that seems only one same thread is used, and that i always have warning message about the type output of selt_t, below code simplified showing main pints.
any ideas where i went wrong ?

First here struct and main:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutexZ;       // Mutex initialize
int array[nn][nn];

struct v
{
  int i, j; // threaded Row,Col
  int n, y; // 
  int iMAX; // 
};

void *transposeM(void *arg);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int Thread_Num = 10; 
  pthread_t t_ID[Thread_Num]; // the number of threads depending on # blocks

  printf("Thread_Num %d\n", Thread_Num);

  struct v *data = (struct v *) malloc(sizeof(struct v));

  int i, j; //loop varables

  //#############################################################
  printf("Matrix Initial before Transpose Done\n"); 
  // printing the Matrix Before any transpose if needed testing

 for (i = 0; i < nn; i++){
  for(j = 0; j< nn; j++){
    array[i][j] = i*nn + j;
    printf("%d ", array[i][j]); 
   }
   printf("\n");}


  //************************************************************/
  // Initialize the mutex 
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutexZ, NULL);
  pthread_attr_t attr; //Set of thread attributes
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);

  int n, y; // Loop Variables for tiling 

  //************************************************************/ 
  //Start of loop transpose:

  int start = 0;

  for (n = 0; n < nn; n += TILE) 
  {
    data->n = n; // row

    for (y = 0; y <= n; y += TILE) {
      data->y = y; // column

      printf("y Tile:%d  \n", y);
      printf("Start before:%d  \n", start);

      //Transpose the other blocks, thread created for each Block transposed

      pthread_create(&(t_ID[start]), NULL, transposeM, (void*) data); // Send the thread to the function
      pthread_join(t_ID[start], NULL);

      if (start < Thread_Num)
      {
        start = start + 1;

      }
      printf("Start after:%d  \n", start);

    } // End the Y column TileJump loop
  } // End of n Row TileJump loop
}
```

Modified according to the notes,

```
void *transposeM(void *arg)
{
  // Transposing the tiles
  struct v *data = arg;
  int i, j; //loop row and column
  int temp = 0;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexZ); //lock the running thread here,so keeps block until thread that holds     mutex releases it

  pthread_t self_t; // To check the thread id - my check not Mandetory to use
  self_t = pthread_self();
  printf("Thread number Main = %u \n ", self_t); //here we used u% coz seems the pthread_t is unsigned long data type

  //*******************************************************
  //here some function to work
  //########################################################

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexZ);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return (NULL);

} // End
```

Comment: "*`pthread_t self_t;`*": Do not use the suffix `_t` for variables, as by convention it inidcates a type.

Comment: The `return (&data);` returns an address on the stack, which is not valid anymore after the thread ended. The statement however will never be reached as `pthread_exit()` had been called prior to it, which itself never returns.

Answer (score 0):

There are two conceptual issues with your code:

1. You pass the same reference/addrerss to each thread, making each thread work on the same data.
2. You join the thread immediately after having created it. As joining block until the thread to be joined ended, this sequentialises the running of all threads.

To get around 1. created a unique instance of what `data` points to for each thread.

To fix 2. move the call to `pthread_join()` out of the loop creating the threads and put it in a 2nd loop run after creation-loop.

```
...

printf("Thread_Num %d\n", Thread_Num);

pthread_t t_ID[Thread_Num]; // the number of threads depending on # blocks
struct v data_ID[Thread_Num] = {0}; // define an instance of data for ech thread

...

for (n = 0; n < nn; n += TILE) //limit of row
{
  struct v * data = data_ID + start; // assign thread specific instance

  data->n = n; // row

  for (y = 0; y <= n; y += TILE) // limit of column -here removd the =n, then diagonal tile is not     transposed
  {
    ...
    pthread_create(&(t_ID[start]), NULL, transposeM, (void*) data); // Send the thread to the function
    ...
  }
} // End the Y column TileJump loop

for (;start >= 0; --start)
{
  pthread_join(t_ID[start], NULL);
}

...
```

Modifications to the thread function:

```
void *transposeM(void *arg)
{
  struct v *data = arg;

  ...

  pthread_t self = pthread_self(); // better naming

  ...

  pthread_exit(NULL); // the thread functions exits here.

  return NULL; // this is never reached, but is necessary to calm down thr compiler.
} // End
```

Comment: thank you, first can you clarify more on how to create unique instances for data? 
2. what do i replace "return(&data)" with ? 3. i have added the external join loop, now it changes the number of the thread number, but now it doesnt enter the function at each loop,.. it enters through the loop, but enters the fuunction like 3 times even when i put number of threads like 50, any ideas why? also what do i use instead of "Self_t" to show threads numbers?

Comment: Please see the code snippets in my updated answer. @user3673183

Comment: hello thanks for your notes, First : its quite weard that my function enters the loop and doesnt even implement the pthread_create, like it jumps over it, for (here it should be around 6 loops entering, its starts entering at last three. i modified above my code to the last note ready to be run. Second, what is format to output pthread_t self to print it ?